# Storing LINQ Query object to an Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ2SQL Query:

```
 //Pulling the Product_ID from the PlanMaster Table from WebEnroll DB!
                var tr = from s in dt.PlanMasters
                         where s.PlanName == productName
                         select new
                         {
                             s.Product_ID
                         };
```

This is pulling Product_ID which is working good. Now I want to ADD a record into another LINQ statement which is here:

```
                CommissionsV2DataContext cv = new CommissionsV2DataContext();
                Entity_Product_Point ev = new Entity_Product_Point();
                ev.Entity_ID = getEntity;
                ev.Product_ID = tr.; ?????
```

I want to store the variable which I am getting from tr (that is Product_ID) to ev.Product_ID.

How should I convert an object to an INT? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your first query returns a collection of objects with an integer property, not a single integer.  You can change your query to this instead:

```
var tr = (
    from s in dt.PlanMasters
    where s.PlanName == productName
    select s.Product_ID).First();
```

Or, more cleanly, IMO:

```
var tr = dt.PlanMasters.First(s => s.PlanName == productName).Product_ID;
```

Comment: I believe the second one still needs to call `Select`

Comment: Nope.  `First` can take a delegate so that the first record that evaluates to `true` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

`tr` is a collection. You have to call `tr.FirstOrDefault().Product_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your linq query to select just the `s.Product_ID` instead of `select new`ing a new anonymous object containing the ID.

```
 var tr = from s in dt.PlanMasters
          where s.PlanName == productName
          select s.Product_ID;
```

Your second code block could then be simply `ev.Product_ID = tr.First();`

```
  CommissionsV2DataContext cv = new CommissionsV2DataContext();
  Entity_Product_Point ev = new Entity_Product_Point();
  ev.Entity_ID = getEntity;
  ev.Product_ID = tr.First();
```

Comment: this won't work - tr is an `IQueryable` and not a number - you'll have to use i.e. `tr.Single()` assuming there is only one - otherwise the query is flawed.

Comment: or `tr.First()`... which is used.

Comment: Guess I hadn't refreshed the page - it wasn't there in the first version

Answer (score 0):

ev.Product_ID = tr.First().Product_ID;